# Copy TCP stream and retransmitt from two sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I need to create a server application that will take the TCP input from an Ethernet webcam and retransmit the packets to two different ports. The reason for this is that I want to connect to a webcam feed with two different programs (using one program locks the feed, making the connection unavailable for anyone else).

Can anyone please say if this is possible and perhaps provide some pseudo code. I am new to network programming and I am not sure on the best way of proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at a basic TCP sockets tutorial such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16916/A-Chat-Application-Using-Asynchronous-TCP-Sockets).

In short, you can use `TcpListener` to detect incoming connections, `TcpClient` to store and interact with those methods server side, and make them client-side. You'd need a listener for the webcam connection, a client to hold that connection, and two more to route it's input into.

---

I've also create <del>[this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11125842)</del> [this one](https://gist.github.com/Broken-Pixels/11126368) (Thanks @jgauffin), that contains an working example program that does this, and two programs you can run to test it and see how it works. It's a bit too detailed for a SO answer, so I'll leave it there and let you examine it yourself.

Comment: Check the comments to you gist.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and example program, it is much more than I was expecting. The only thing that concerns me is if the webcam protocol will work with two clients (I will have a chance to find out in the next few days).